# Would it be possible to have optional ForeignKey on delete with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, database, linq, asp.net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.0

Using the following Models:

```
public class User {

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public List<UserLog> UserLogs { get; set; }

}
public class UserLog {

    [Key]
    public long LogId { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string LogAction { get; set; }

    public DateTime LogCreatedOn { get; set; }

    public string By { get; set; }
}
```

I'm able to do the insert/update of both User and UserLogs with one SaveChangesAsync().

The issue I'm having is when I do add an entry to UserLog, then remove the User, finally, call SaveChangesAsync(); the UserLog was never added.

e.g.

```
_db.UserLogs.Add(userLogItem); //never gets added.
//await _db.SaveChangesAsync(); //even trying to call this line right after.
_db.Users.Remove(user);
await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I define my models when I have one to many relationship.

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserLog> UserLogs { get; set; }
}

public class UserLog
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long LogId { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string LogAction { get; set; }

    public DateTime LogCreatedOn { get; set; }

    public string By { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I am trying it. Though, the UserLog is not being inserted. My code is like: _db.UserLogs.Add(userLog);_db.Remove(user);await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

Comment: What exactly you try to do? I suppose you want to add a log for a specific user. If this is what you try to do then your code is not right.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to add UserLog with LogAction="Deleted" before deleting the actual record from Users table , with one SaveChanges call. May I ask if what's the proper code for it? Thank you.